# Track down and upgrade a hard to find ruby gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, vagrant, bundler

While running vagrant, which is presumably written in Ruby, I got the following error (`vagrant --help` produces that same error message):

```
$ vagrant plugin install vagrant-hostmanager
Vagrant experienced a version conflict with some installed plugins!
This usually happens if you recently upgraded Vagrant. As part of the
upgrade process, some existing plugins are no longer compatible with
this version of Vagrant. The recommended way to fix this is to remove
your existing plugins and reinstall them one-by-one. To remove all
plugins:

    rm -r ~/.vagrant.d/plugins.json ~/.vagrant.d/gems

Note if you have an alternate VAGRANT_HOME environmental variable
set, the folders above will be in that directory rather than your
user's home directory.

The error message is shown below:

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    vagrant (= 1.8.4) was resolved to 1.8.4, which depends on
      bundler (~> 1.12.5)

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (1.11.2)
This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`?
```

After checking that `~/.vagrant.d/gems` contains nothing except `ruby`, I `sudo gem update` and check `bundler --version`: 1.12.5. Bundler has been updated. Unfortunately, I get the same error on the next run. Vagrant seems to be importing gems from a different location than where `gem update` saves them. After some googling, I discover `gem env`:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.5.1
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.3.1 (2016-04-26 patchlevel 112) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/dan/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby2.3
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/dan/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /var/lib/gems/2.3.0
     - /home/dan/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
     - /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/rubygems-integration/2.3.0
     - /usr/share/rubygems-integration/2.3.0
     - /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all
```

Looking in the `gems` directories of the GEM PATHS list, I only see a `bundler-1.12.5` gem. I know that bundler 1.11.2 must exist somewhere on my system if Vagrant is loading it, so `locate bundler-1.11.2`:

```
/usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/specifications/bundler-1.11.2.gemspec
```

What is that gemspec? Do I have to specify its location somehow when I am upgrading the bundler gem, in order to keep some metadata up to date?

I did just recently update vagrant, using `apt-get`, from a more recent Debian package than the one in my system's package repository.

Comment: Please don't use "edit" or "update" tags in your text. Instead, incorporate the information in as if it was added initially. We can tell what was added when if necessary, because Stack Overflow maintains a history of edits for questions and answers. Readability is much more important than the order of edits.